# Apache Beam, NoSuchMethodError on BigQueryIO.WriteTableRows()?

Tags: java, apache-beam, dataflow

I've recently upgraded an existing pipeline from dataflow 1.x to dataflow 2.x, and I'm seeing an error that doesn't make sense to me. I'll put the relevant code below, then include the error I'm seeing.

```
// This is essentially the final step in our pipeline, where we write
// one of the side outputs from the pipeline to a BigQuery table

results.get(matchedTag)
  .apply("CountBackfill", Count.<String>perElement())
  .apply("ToReportRow", ParDo.of(new ToReportRow()))
  // at this point, there is now a PCollection<TableRow>
  .apply("WriteReport", BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
    .to(reportingDataset + ".AttributeBackfill_" + dayStr)
    .withSchema(ReportSchema.get())
    .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE)
    .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED));


/*
* Create a TableRow from a key/value pair
*/
public static class ToReportRow extends DoFn<KV<String, Long>, TableRow> {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @ProcessElement
  public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws InterruptedException {
    KV<String, Long> row = c.element();

    c.output(new TableRow()
      .set(ReportSchema.ID, row.getKey())
      .set(ReportSchema.COUNT, row.getValue()));
  }
}
```

And here is the error I am seeing:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
>   at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO$Write.expand(BigQueryIO.java:1426)
>   at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO$Write.expand(BigQueryIO.java:989)
>   at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:525) at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:479) at
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection.apply(PCollection.java:297) at
>   com.prod.merge.DailyUniqueProfiles.buildPipeline(DUP.java:106)
>   at com.prod.merge.MergePipeline.main(MergePipeline.java:91)

The line `.apply("WriteReport", BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()` is line 106 in `DUP.java`, so that is the line I suspect is wrong somehow.

Any ideas on what the problem might be?

Comment: The problem appears to be with conflicting versions of guava, although I'm not yet sure what the conflict is arising from.

Comment: I'm also hit with the same error. Were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: @Vetri I just posted my solution below. Hopefully it works for you too.

Comment: Thanks @Max - your solution gave me an hint and I fixed it. Posted my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem ended up being in the maven dependencies. After adding the following dependency, and recompiling with `mvn`, the error went away.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
  <version>22.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an older version of guava is being pulled in by a transitive dependency. Below changes to dependencies worked for me.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-services-bigquery</artifactId>
    <version>v2-rev295-1.22.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <!-- Exclude an old version of guava that is being pulled in by a transitive dependency of google-api-client -->
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
       </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```